# React: Adding an input component via a button and updating its state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a button that will add a new input element to a page and then as I type display its changes.

However when I type into the input fields in `<Input />`, for some reason the state isn't changing. **The input fields stay blank.**

Out of curiosity, I removed the button that adds the `<Input />` component and ran it with one `<Input />` field on the page. When I type into one of the input fields, I can see my text.

It seems that when I add a new component to the page and try to change the state, something is off.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function Input(props) {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div>
            <div><input name="pitchName" value={props.currentValue.pitchName} placeholder="Pitch Name" onChange = {props.updateNewPitch}/></div>
            <div><input name="shortCut" value={props.currentValue.shortcut} placeholder="Short cut" onChange = {props.updateNewPitch} /></div>
            <div><input name="subject" value={props.currentValue.subject} placeholder="Subject" onChange = {props.updateNewPitch} /></div>
            <div><textarea name="pitch" value={props.currentValue.pitch} onChange = {props.updateNewPitch}/></div>
            <button type="submit" onClick={props.savePitch} >Add Pitch</button>
        </div>
    )
}

// function SavedPitches(props)


class Form extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputList: [],
            addNewPitch: {
                pitchName: '',
                shortCut: '',
                subject: '',
                pitch: ''
            },
            savedPitches: []
        };
        this.onAddBtnClick = this.onAddBtnClick.bind(this)
        this.savePitch = this.savePitch.bind(this)
        this.updateNewPitch = this.updateNewPitch.bind(this)
    }

    updateNewPitch(e){
        this.setState({addNewPitch: {...this.state.addNewPitch, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}})

    }


    onAddBtnClick(event){
        const inputList = this.state.inputList;
        this.setState({
            inputList: inputList.concat(
                <Input savePitch={this.savePitch} 
                       currentValue = {this.state.addNewPitch} 
                       updateNewPitch={this.updateNewPitch} 
                />
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onAddBtnClick}>Add input</button>
                <div></div>
                {
                    this.state.inputList
                }
            </div>

        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Form />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason is because you are storing the `Input` (UI element) in state variable, and that variable is not getting update only values are getting updated in a separate state variable `addNewPitch`.

**Suggestion**:

1- Storing UI elements in state variable is not a good idea, always store value in state and all the ui logic should be inside render function.

2- Use a state variable and toggle the `Input` (UI element) on the basis of that.

Check working solution (check the values on `addNewPitch` inside render it will get updated properly):

```js
function Input(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div><input name="pitchName" value={props.currentValue.pitchName} placeholder="Pitch Name" onChange = {props.updateNewPitch}/></div>
            <div><input name="shortCut" value={props.currentValue.shortcut} placeholder="Short cut" onChange = {props.updateNewPitch} /></div>
            <div><input name="subject" value={props.currentValue.subject} placeholder="Subject" onChange = {props.updateNewPitch} /></div>
            <div><textarea name="pitch" value={props.currentValue.pitch} onChange = {props.updateNewPitch}/></div>
            <button type="submit" onClick={props.savePitch} >Add Pitch</button>
        </div>
    )
}


class Form extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputList: [],
            addNewPitch: {
                pitchName: '',
                shortCut: '',
                subject: '',
                pitch: ''
            },
            savedPitches: []
        };
        this.onAddBtnClick = this.onAddBtnClick.bind(this)
        this.savePitch = this.savePitch.bind(this)
        this.updateNewPitch = this.updateNewPitch.bind(this)
    }

    savePitch() {
    }

    updateNewPitch(e){
       this.setState({addNewPitch: {...this.state.addNewPitch, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}})
    }


    onAddBtnClick(event){
        const inputList = this.state.inputList;
        this.setState({
           show: true,
           addNewPitch: {
                pitchName: '',
                shortCut: '',
                subject: '',
                pitch: ''
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        console.log('addNewPitch', this.state.addNewPitch);
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onAddBtnClick}>Add input</button>
                <div></div>
                {
                    this.state.show && <Input 
                      savePitch={this.savePitch} 
                      currentValue = {this.state.addNewPitch} 
                      updateNewPitch={this.updateNewPitch} 
                  />
                }
            </div>

        )
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Form />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'/>
```